# How to split Golang strings without deleting separator?

Tags: string, go, split

According to the answer at [How to split a string and assign it to variables in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551354/how-to-split-a-string-and-assign-it-to-variables-in-golang) splitting a string results in an array of strings where the separator is not present in any of the strings in the array. Is there a way to split strings such that the separator is on the last line of a given string?

e.x.

```
s := strings.split("Potato:Salad:Popcorn:Cheese", ":")
for _, element := range s {
    fmt.Printf(element)
}
```

outputs:

```
Potato
Salad
Popcorn
Cheese
```

I wish to output the following instead:

```
Potato:
Salad:
Popcorn:
Cheese
```

I know I could theoretically append ":" to the end of each element except for the last, but I'm looking for a more general, elegant solution if possible.

Comment: You can try to search for `:`, and get the sub string via index, without a `split()` method.

Comment: you can use `Regex` https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [SplitAfter](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitAfter).

```
s := strings.SplitAfter("Potato:Salad:Popcorn:Cheese", ":")
  for _, element := range s {
  fmt.Println(element)
}
// Potato:
// Salad:
// Popcorn:
// Cheese
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yPrIyBkEwCD)

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by daplho great and simple. Sometimes I just like to provide an alternative to remove the magic of a function

```
package main

import "fmt"

var s = "Potato:Salad:Popcorn:Cheese"

func main() {
    a := split(s, ':')
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func split(s string, sep rune) []string {
    var a []string
    var j int
    for i, r := range s {
        if r == sep {
            a = append(a, s[j:i+1])
            j = i + 1
        }
    }
    a = append(a, s[j:])
    return a
}
```

https://goplay.space/#h9sDd1gjjZw

As a side note, the standard lib version is better than the hasty one above

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkSplit-4             5000000           339 ns/op
BenchmarkSplitAfter-4       10000000           143 ns/op
```

So go with that lol

Comment: As golang is open-source, a peek under the hood readily reveals SplitAfter's implementation. It utilizes the `genSplit` function: https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/master/src/strings/strings.go#240

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to get the proper result**.

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
    )

    func main() {
        str := "Potato:Salad:Popcorn:Cheese"
        a := strings.SplitAfter(str, ":")
        for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
            fmt.Println(a[i])
        }
    }
```