# How to split a string but keep delimiters as separate elements

Tags: go

I have several strings that include various symbols like the following two examples:

```
z=y+x

@symbol
```

and I want to split the strings such that I have the resulting slices:

```
[z = y + x]

[@ symbol]
```

A few things I've looked at and tried:

1. I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters) but it seems as though golang doesn't support [lookarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305934/9696311).
2. I know this [solution exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851597/how-to-split-golang-strings-without-deleting-separator) using strings.SplitAfter, but I'm looking to have the delimiters as separate elements.
3. I tried replacing the symbol (e.g. "+") with some variant (e.g. "~+~") and doing a split on the surrounding characters (e.g. "~"), but this solution is far from elegant and runs into problems if I need to do a conditional replacement depending on the symbol ([which golang doesn't seem to support either](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)).

Perhaps I've misunderstood some of the previous question and their respective solutions.

Comment: Am i right, that you just want to turn string into array?

Comment: Is the split set known? Do you intend to pass that to the splitting function?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin yes that is correct

Comment: @icza yes it would be, say for now it includes [@, +, =]

Answer (score 1):

I used a modified version of Go's strings.Split implementation https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go?s=7505:7539#L245

```golang
func Test(te *testing.T) {
    t := tester.New(te)
    t.Assert().Equal(splitCharsInclusive("z=y+x", "=+"), []string{"z", "=", "y", "+", "x"})
    t.Assert().Equal(splitCharsInclusive("@symbol", "@"), []string{"", "@", "symbol"})

}

func splitCharsInclusive(s, chars string) (out []string) {
    for {
        m := strings.IndexAny(s, chars)
        if m < 0 {
            break
        }
        out = append(out, s[:m], s[m:m+1])
        s = s[m+1:]
    }
    out = append(out, s)
    return
}
```

This is limited to single characters to split on. And passing something like `splitCharsInclusive("(z)(y)(x)", "()")` might not get you the output you want, as you'd get a few empty strings in the response. But hopefully this is a good starting point for the modifications you need.

Also, Go's version that I've linked calculates the length of the output array in advance, this is a nice optimization that I've decided to omit, but would likely be good to add back.