# Convert one unicode string to array

Tags: go, unicode-escapes

How can I convert this string into an array or slice in Golang ?
Separators are unicode caracters \u001e and \uu1d.

```
inputString="\u001e456\u001dBernard Janv\u001d0022000\u001d250\u001d804\u001d1169\u001d\u001d168"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string and assign it to variables in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551354/how-to-split-a-string-and-assign-it-to-variables-in-golang)

Comment: what is your expected output??  Do you want to remove these Unicode in your output??

Comment: Separators are only these two Unicode characters: \u001e and \u001d ? Or can there be others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strings.Fields](https://pkg.go.dev/strings?tab=doc#FieldsFunc) to split the string:

```
inputString := "\u001e456\u001dBernard Janv\u001d0022000\u001d250\u001d804\u001d1169\u001d\u001d168"
parts := strings.FieldsFunc(inputString, func(r rune) bool {
    return r == '\u001d' || r == '\u001e'
})
for _, part := range parts {
    fmt.Println(part)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/x_le2P3h8ry